# Email Approval Script encountered a server error

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I have done an email approval script following James Ferreira's youtube tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eduG0XZ9mDs&list=PL73FAFB4E8303DA97&index=4&feature=plcp).

The email sending of request was successful but the "Approve" / "Reject" was not. Clicking either "Approve" or "Reject", google will give me an error: "Google Docs has encountered a server error." .....

Any idea what might be causing the error or how best can I debug this please?

Thanks.

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the URL you are constructing and sending in the email is correct. You should use the URL that is shown when you publish your script as a service.